# Unable to locate package MongoDB 7 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB 7 on Ubuntu 22.04 following the official documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ and the apt package manager does not find the package in the https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 repository.

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg curl

curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \
sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \
--dearmor

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

What am I doing wrong, Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think some repository was down because when I tried again a few days later, it worked.